# How would use the heap function in Crossfilter.js? When would you use it?

Tags: crossfilter

I have started to get more involved with data visualisation, I have started using d3.js for some of the projects that I am working. I recently came across crossfilter.js and I was curious as how the heap function implemented. And when should it be used?